# Is there a way to set different colors for folders in the explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any way in vscode to specify different folders to be different colors?
For example if I wanted my "tests" folder to always be highlighted red to quickly find it etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot set this directly.

You could use an [icon theme extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_adding-a-new-icon-theme) could give `test` folders a different icon. See [this extension](https://github.com/EmmanuelBeziat/vscode-great-icons) for how it customizes the `node_modules` folder icon for example

Comment: I can't believe this feature is still not available after 5 years.

Comment: @Nick it is now, did you see Jacob's answer?

Answer (score 10):

Update 2023: Visual Studio Code has opened up the API's a little bit, allowing us to configure a specific color in the explorer view and in tabs, unless the application has forced a color (for example modified file in source control or error). But in these cases we can add a custom symbol to the right. (See screenshot below)

I created a extension that leverages these API's, you can try it out here: (Just released, feel free to post any issues you may find) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisbyDev.folder-path-color

It will look something like this: (See "file.php" to understand what I mean with forced color)
[image: Screenshot of extension]

Even though it may not be perfect, it will at least allow for some sort of visual separation between projects.
The code is open source if you have any concerns.

Comment: I LOVE it! Thanks so much!

Comment: I love it very much. The only issue is that it matches all folder names starting from `lean` (e.g. `lean-toolchain`), and not only `lean`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is any manual preference settings for folder colours.
But, We can use plugins for making our folders identify such as  - VSCODE-ICONS etc

Answer (score 0):

There is another one plugin, I've developed this. Please feel free to try ;)

> FolderColorizer

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyEgorov.folder-color
Easy to use. just right click context menu and choose "Colorize"

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7Nv.png)

Comment: Answers that don't explicitly state that you're the developer of the solution you're suggesting are considered spam

Comment: @SergeyEgorov can u add option to colorize all folder (not files), some only want to separate folders from files on the tree visually